# How to extend map operator in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I want to create a new operator like `map`. but the different is whatever map returns I need to clone it using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))`.

Because I return an object from my store (`Subject`), and I don't want somebody to change it, or it's inner properties.

I copy the `map` singture to my `mapToVM` function, but I can't find any way to use `pipe` or manipulate the return results.

Is it possible to change the return results by wrapping the `map` operator?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-ben-5ukhhw?file=/src/index.ts)

So I try to return the `map` function and take the source as `Observable`, but typescript

```
import { map, Observable, OperatorFunction, Subject } from "rxjs";

console.clear();

const store = new Subject<{ company: { id: number } }>();

store.pipe(map((s) => s.company)).subscribe((company) => {
  console.log({ company });
});

function mapToVM<T, R>(
  project: (value: T, index: number) => R
): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  // JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source));
  return map(project);
}

store.pipe(mapToVM((s) => s.company)).subscribe((company) => {
  console.log({ company });
});

store.next({ company: { id: 1 } });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the static pipe function:

```js
function jsonClone<T>(): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return pipe(map((source) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source))));
}
```

[Full CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-cache-sy7hh8?file=/src/index.ts:271-390)